# Getting Internal Server Error during template parsing. What's happening?

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

So I'm building a simple taco order application and got this "template parsing" error when I submitted the form at `/design`.

[image: Image 1]

[image: image 2]

Here is the thymeleaf code for the `orderForm.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${tacoOrder}">
    <h1>Order your taco creations!</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.jpeg}"/>

    <h3>Your tacos in this order:</h3>
    <a th:href="@{/design}" id="another">Design another taco</a><br/>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="taco : ${tacoOrder.tacos}">
            <span th:text="${taco.name}">taco name</span></li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
    <label for="deliveryName">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryName}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryName')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryName}">Delivery Name Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryStreet">Street address: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryStreet}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryStreet')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryStreet}">Delivery Street Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryCity">City: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryCity}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryCity')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryCity}">Delivery City Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryState">State: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryState}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryState')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryState}">Delivery State Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryZip">Zip code: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryZip}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryZip')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryZip}">Delivery Zip Error</span>
    <br/>

    <h3>Here's how I'll pay...</h3>
    <label for="ccNumber">Credit Card #: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccNumber}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccNumber')}"
          th:errors="*{ccNumber}">CC Num Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccExpiration">Expiration: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccExpiration}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccExpiration')}"
          th:errors="*{ccExpiration}">CC Expiration Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccCVV">CVV: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccCVV}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccCVV')}"
          th:errors="*{ccCVV}">CC CVV Error</span>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for `OrderController.java`

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import tacos.TacoOrder;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm() {
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid TacoOrder order, Errors errors, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "orderForm";
        }
        log.info("Order submitted: {}", order);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

My TacoOrder class:

```java
public class TacoOrder {
    @NotBlank(message="Delivery name is required")
    private String deliveryName;

    @NotBlank(message="Street is required")
    private String deliveryStreet;

    @NotBlank(message="City is required")
    private String deliveryCity;

    @NotBlank(message="State is required")
    private String deliveryState;

    @NotBlank(message="Zipcode is required")
    private String deliveryZip;

    @CreditCardNumber(message="Not a valid credit card number")
    private String ccNumber;

    @Pattern(regexp="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([2-9][0-9])$", message="Must be formatted MM/YY")
    private String ccExpiration;

    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=0, message="Invalid CVV")
    private String ccCVV;

    private List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTaco(Taco taco) {
        this.tacos.add(taco);
    }

}
```

My Taco class:

```java
public class Taco {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
}
```

I inspected the `orderForm.html`, `tacoorder.java`, and checked all the controller classes but can't seem to find why I'm getting this error.
What's happening?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: 'tacos' is a private field - I quess, it is the reason. Either make field public or add setters and getters

Comment: @SveKamenska I'm using lombok which I've read automatically generates getter, setter and other important methods.

Comment: But you did not put any lombok annotations on your class + exception error says the same: you don't have public field takos, nor it has public getter

Answer (score 0):

ThymeLeaf uses getters and setters to access the fields. Currently 'tacos' is a private field of TacoOrder, so it is not visible to ThymeLeaf.

Add getters and setters to the fields - it should work then.